# SSL certificate on javax.net.ssl conflicts with Azure storage sdk

Tags: spring-boot, azure, ssl, db2, azure-storage

I am working on a Java based application using Springboot where I need to connect with DB2 to pull data and Azure Storage for some download/backup operations.

While setting up these two I am **stuck on a conflict over SSL** authentication.

I am using connection string to connect with Azure Blog Storage through azure-storage SDK as mentioned below

```
private void processStoredFiles() {
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = // Create through CONNECTION_STRING;
    var blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.getContainerReference(blobContainer);
    
    var blobDirectory = container.getDirectoryReference(blobFolder);
    var blobFiles = blobDirectory.listBlobs()
    for (ListBlobItem blobFile : blobFiles) {
        // blob handling
    }
}
```

This code works fine when there is no SSL certificate on the environment/properties.

My DB2 connection requires SSL certificate and while creating Data source I need to set few System properties to make it work as mentioned below.

```
public HikariDataSource createDatasource() {
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(vaultHelper.getSecret("DB-URL-WHSE"));
    
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("keepAliveTimeOut", 30);
    
    hikariDataSource.setDataSourceProperties(properties);
    
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD"));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "SSL_KEY_STORE_BASE64_FILE_PATH");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "SSL_TRUST_STORE_BASE64_FILE_PATH");
    
    return hikariDataSource;
}
```

Note: **Datasource is being created as a standard Spring Bean with singleton scope.**

After adding DB2 connection and setting up system properties, I am getting following error when I try to use Azure storage. Below is the exception I am getting

```
An exception has occurred in running CriticalBatch Job: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner","logger_name":"com.XXX.CriticalBatchApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.XXX.CriticalBatchApplication.main(CriticalBatchApplication.java:59)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
    at com.XXX.client.BlobStorageClient.downloadFiles(BlobStorageClient.java:102)
    at com.XXX.service.BlobService.downloadFiles(BlobService.java:46)
    at com.XXX.service.BlobService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$acd6c230.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)
    at com.XXX.service.BlobService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b66da41.downloadFiles(<generated>)
    at com.XXX.service.BlobReader.fillBlob(BlobReader.java:87)
    at com.XXX.service.CriticalService.processCritical(CriticalService.java:69)
    at com.XXX.CriticalBatchApplication.run(CriticalBatchApplication.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException:
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:220)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:298)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1417)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1597)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1525)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:115)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

I tried to clearup all properties using System.clearProperty() method at different levels. but it did not resolve the issue.

Any help in setting up Azure while having some SSL certificate on path is much appreciated